# SQL: Union or Self Join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table:  user(id, date, task)

The task field contains either "download" or "upload"

I want to figure out the number of users who do each action per day.

**Output**: date, # of users who downloaded, # of users who uploaded

I first ran into the issue of using a subquery in the aggregate count function of the select, so I thought I should be using a self join here to break apart the data in the "task" column.

I thought I could create to tables for each case and then combine those and count, but I am having trouble finishing this out:

SELECT id, date, task as task_download
FROM user
WHERE task = 'download'

SELECT id, date, task as task_upload
FROM user
WHERE task = 'upload'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, neither nor. Just a query like this will do the job:

```
select `date`, 
    count(distinct case when task = 'download' then id else null end) as downloads, 
    count(distinct case when task = 'upload' then id else null end) as uploads
from user
where  task in ('download', 'upload')
group by `date`
```

assuming, `date` is a column containing only the date part and not the complete timestamp and `id` is the user id. You can use the `distinct` keyword within aggregate functions, that's what I did here.

To have this query run appropriately fast, I recommend using an index on `task,date`

If, however, `date` contains the complete timestamp (i.e. including the time-part) you would want to group differently:

```
select `date`, 
    count(distinct case when task = 'download' then id else null end) as downloads, 
    count(distinct case when task = 'upload' then id else null end) as uploads
from user
where  task in ('download', 'upload')
group by date(`date`)
```

Comment: Note that this counts the number of uploads and downloads, not the number of users who performed those actions  (e.g. if one user performs seventeen downloads and four uploads in a day, and that is the only user that performed a task on that day, this query would return counts of 17 and 4, not 1 and 1.  .

Comment: @spencer7593 it returns the number of uploads and downloads per user on each day. Not the number of users. See the `group`-statement. I assume that 'id' is the user id (that's not made clear in the question).

Comment: The specification was somewhat ambiguous (no sample data, no expected output), but I think the requirement was to return a count of *users*   "**# of users** who downloaded" ,  not "# of downloads".  I interpreted that to mean that one user performing eight downloads on a date should be counted as one user, not eight users. (I don't think `id` needs to be part of the result or the group by,  if that's a surrogate primary key, but again, the specification is somewhat ambiguous.)

Comment: That's indeed right, I misread that. Thanks for clearing that, I will update my answer

Comment: @Psi this makes a lot of sense, if i wanted to order my dates for say that last month, would i just add the following: Order by date DESC, Limit 30;

Answer (score 3):

```
select  `date`, 
COUNT( distinct CASE WHEN task = 'download' then id end ) 'download', 
COUNT( distinct CASE WHEN task = 'upload' then id end ) 'upload'
from user
group by  `date`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with sub-queries, e.g.:

```
SELECT `date` AS `day`,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activity WHERE date = day AND activity = 'upload') AS upload_count,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM activity WHERE date = day AND activity = 'download') AS download_count
FROM activity
GROUP BY date;
```

Here's the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5b37d/3/0).

Comment: This returns a count of the downloads for a given date, not necessarily a number of users. i.e. if one user performed four downloads on the same date... should that count as four towards the total, or as should it count as one?  (The specification is somewhat ambiguous, but I think it called for a count of users... "**# of users** who downloaded".)

Answer (score 1):

First count distinct users by date and task, and then sum users depending on each task by date.

```
select date,
       sum(case when task = 'upload' then num_users else 0 end) as "upload",
       sum(case when task = 'download' then num_users else 0 end) as "download"
from  (       
       select   date, task, count(distinct id) num_users
       from     usert
       group by date, task
      ) x
group by date
;
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/ZACFB64945

Answer (score 1):

If you want the distinct users, then that suggests `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT date, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN task = 'upload' THEN userid END) as uploads,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN task = 'download' THEN userid END) as downloads
FROM user
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

If you want distinct *actions* then you can do this as:

```
SELECT date, 
       SUM( (task = 'upload')::int ) as uploads,
       SUM( (task = 'download')::int) as downloads
FROM user
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

This uses a convenient Postgres shorthand for counting the boolean expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use conditional aggregation.

To get a count of the **number of users** that performed at least one upload on a given date (but only increment the count by one for that user for that date, even if that user performed more than one upload on the same date), we can use a `COUNT(DISTINCT user)` expression.

To get a count of the total number of uploads, we can use a COUNT or SUM.

```
SELECT DATE(t.date) AS `date`
     , COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t.task='upload'  ,t.user,NULL)) AS cnt_users_who_uploaded
     , COUNT(DISTINCT IF(t.task='download',t.user,NULL)) AS cnt_users_who_downloaded
     , SUM(IF(t.task='upload'  ,1,0))                    AS cnt_uploads
     , SUM(IF(t.task='download',1,0))                    AS cnt_downloads
  FROM user t
 GROUP BY DATE(t.date)
 ORDER BY DATE(t.date)
```

---

Note: this will not return counts of zero for dates where there are no rows for that `date` does not appear in the table.